# Class Library - References - Reusability with Copy Local?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a class library project, lets call it CoreLib.
CoreLib has two references to 3rd party DLL files 1.dll and 2.dll

Because I love reusability so much, I want to be able to use CoreLib in as many places as possible/needed.

So if I had a project called BigProjectA and another project called BigProjectB and they needed to leverage the functionality provided by CoreLib, all I would have to do is add a reference to CoreLib in those projects (BigProjectA and BigProjectB).

That is fine, except when I go to copy over my output folder (bin directory) to another person's computer, I can't guarantee that they have 1.dll and 2.dll on their machines.

For that, I just set Copy Local to True for 1.dll and 2.dll references in the CoreLib project.

When building the CoreLib project I can see 1.dll, 2.dll, and CoreLib.dll files.  That is PERFECT!

But in the projects referencing CoreLib, only CoreLib.dll is copied over, not 1.dll and 2.dll.

Am I missing something?  Copy Local set to True, but only copies for the CoreLib project.  So even though they are in the same solution, and I'm adding CoreLib as a project reference to the other projects, I still dont see 1.dll and 2.dll copying out to the other bin/Debug, bin/Release folders of the other projects (BigProjectA and BigProjectB).

Is there an easy solution?

Comment: The references are: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good answers guys....but I actually just ended up using ILMerge. Seemed safer/less annoying.

Thank you though

Comment: which dlls do you merge? CoreLib.dll + 1.dll + 2.dll?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to either:

1. reference 1.DLL and 2.DLL in projects which have a binary reference to CoreData.DLL
2. Add CoreData as a project reference to BigProjectA and BigProjectB instead of as a binary reference

In the first scenario, CoreData's dependencies are not automatically output by the compiler. If the CoreData project is added to the solution, its dependencies *will* be output. Hence, to use CoreData as a binary reference, you must also reference its dependencies.

Comment: Missed the fact that it's stated in the question a project reference is being used. My apologies...

Comment: I would hate to do solution 1 but that would be the last thing I would do.  Solution 2 IS what I did though.  It is a project reference, and STILL the files are not being copied over.  GAC related???

Comment: Are you compiling in Visual Studio, or via MSBuild? I've experienced a problem with secondary references in the latter...

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, just trying to build in the IDE and checking the folder in Windows Explorer. Very basic stuff. Target Framework .NET 4.0

Comment: added the reference DLL's in my OP (comment).  Try it out guys

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong. In projects `BigProjectA`  and `BigProjectB`  you have a references to  only `CoreLib`, so they "care" about coping only it, cause they have no any clue about it's dependencies. What you can do to resolve these kind of issue, is to add for example PostBuildVEent in your `BigProject..` to copy also `CoreLib` dependencies.

Or add reference to `CoreLib` project, if you can.

Another solution,  is to consider DI like a technique to avoid strong coupling of references. So, if in `BigProjectA` or `B` you don't care about functionality provided by 3rd party libraries in `CoreLib`, for you should be enough to just copy `CoreLib`.

Comment: The reference is to CoreLib project.  It is a project reference.  That is what is boggling my mind right now.  I have a similar setup with different DLL files in another solution and it works just fine.  Is it possible that Visual Studio checks to see if it is present in the GAC first???

Comment: ...and I try to avoid Pre/Post BuildEvents like the plague.

Comment: @Issa: no, I don't think so. Never listen about something like this.

Comment: @Issa: there is nothing bad with post build events. If your project is not about to scale with amazing speed that you need to rewrite them every day, write them down once and forget about them. They just work.

Comment: added the reference DLL's in my OP (comment). Try it out guys