# Reference local class library for development and package for test and prod?

Tags: .net-core

I am developing using vs code and want to create a class library and use it in a project (an Azure Functions project) so it can be reused. I want them to remain two different projects, but during development I want to edit both. In testing and production, I want to use the package for the Functions project, which I expect to publish in a private GitHub repo.

Is there a way to configure the .csproj to use the local project in development and the package everywhere else? This is my .csproj which is where I would put the references, do I put the local reference in here and is there a mechanism to use a different reference for testing and production?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78127464</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.1"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I can put a local project reference like:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ersistence\persistence.csproj" />
```

in the file, but I only want that if its in the development envrionment.

This post, [Class Library - References - Reusability with Copy Local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521850/class-library-references-reusability-with-copy-local), is a little old (12+ years). I saw this one, [Reference class libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72675434/reference-class-libraries), which shows how to reference a project, but is there any way to use one setting for development and one setting for everything else?